# Communicate with a JetDirect print server

Tags: sdk, vb.net-2010

Is there an SDK available from HP to communicate with their print servers?  Or, is there a method within vb.net (2010) that would do the same job?  I need to know if a certain printer is available/on-line before printing to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with a barcode licensing server and not an issue with a JetDirect/HP wireless print server.  This question may be closed.